# is it possible to get to the logs of the container while inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, docker-container

my project is running inside a docker container - `web_container` and I need to get a way to get `web_container`'s logs through the project

i tried running the command `docker logs web_container >> file.log;`, but as I understand it, the command is not recognized inside the docker container

is there any way to get the logs while in the container?

Comment: what you see in docker logs is just what is written to stdout/stderr in your container. Suppose your program is the only things that runs there, whatever it writes to stdout/stderr will be in docker logs. So you dont need to jump thorugh those hoops, you already know what you are writing to stdout since your program has the control.

Comment: Is there any way to write these records to a file?  
@The Fool

Comment: Most logging libraries have "write to a file" as a very prominent option, if you're using a logging framework.  But, why do you need to read back your own logs; would it be better to keep that data in-process in some more structure form?

Comment: you can change the CMD to something like `CMD ./myapp >> logs.txt 2>&1`. Note that this data will be lost if the container is removed. But I this David Maze is right. Conceptionally, it doesn't make sense to write to a file and then read it again from the same process. Why bother writing/reading it in the first place, you have the data at your disposal already.

Comment: one reason might be to monitor said app logs with dockers HEALTHCHECK to look for app zombie failures

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logs are stored on host, so you cannot access them in container. But it is possible to mount (`docker run -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/whereever/you/want2/mount:ro`) the folder inside the container (read-only preferred).
By default it is here `/var/lib/docker/containers/[container-id]/[container-id]-json.log`.
While the container ID you can obtain with `cat /proc/self/cgroup | grep -o  -e "docker-.*.scope" | head -n 1 | sed "s/docker-\(.*\).scope/\\1/"` from inside the container. (Maybe depends on your system, anyways it is in `/proc/self/cgroup`).

**Remark:**
This is a technically working answer to your question. For most use-cases the comments of David and The Fool are the more elegant way solving that.

Comment: there is no such directory `/var/lib/docker/containers/` inside the container

Comment: Sure, as written you have to mount it.. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only `docker run -v /var/lib/docker/containers:/whereever/you/want2/mount:ro`

Comment: as I understand in your answer, the log files are copied to the container at the beginning  of build container?

Comment: i think there might be simpler ways than mounting stuff in your local fs for instance - there is also `docker logs` command if u havent heard of it :) Enjoy!

Comment: No. With a mount you can add permanent file storage to a container. One type is the docker volume which acts like a virtual hard drive for the container. Other possibility is to mount a directory from host machine into the container. This is live, so if you change something on host (like writing to log-file) it is available inside container and vice versa. So if you mount the log-directory you can access the current logs. Also nice for development: map your source code inside the container and you can debug the container without rebuild.